# censReg and Dates

Tags: r, regression, covariance

I am having difficulty calculating a variance-covariance matrix when using the censReg function.  My example dataset (posted below) does not have any censored data so that i can compare the results with the simple linear regression (lm) function.  I will need to apply this to datasets with censored data in the future so i need to know how/why it works the way it does.

the issue:  censReg seems to have problems dealing with dates (either as class Date or converted to class numeric).  Here is a simple dataset:

```
X = data.table(EVENT=as.Date(c(ISOdate(2011,1,1),ISOdate(2011,1,2),ISOdate(2011,1,3),ISOdate(2011,1,4))),
               VAL = c(12.2,62.4,38.9,65.7),
               INTERP = c(126.42,124.26,125.53,124.48))
```

when i pass this through the censReg function i get the following results:

```
CEN = censReg(formula=log(VAL) ~ INTERP + EVENT,data=X)
vcov(CEN)
            (Intercept) INTERP EVENT logSigma
(Intercept)         Inf    Inf   Inf      Inf
INTERP              Inf    Inf   Inf      Inf
EVENT               Inf    Inf   Inf      Inf
logSigma            Inf    Inf   Inf      Inf
```

if i change the date (in this case "EVENT") field to a smaller number (seq(1,4,1)), then the vcov function will calculate something.

```
X = data.table(EVENT=seq(1,4,1),
               VAL = c(12.2,62.4,38.9,65.7),
               INTERP = c(126.42,124.26,125.53,124.48))

CEN = censReg(formula=log(VAL) ~ INTERP + EVENT,data=X)
vcov(CEN)
              (Intercept)        INTERP         EVENT      logSigma
(Intercept)  1.112009e+02 -8.802189e-01 -4.073329e-01  5.874470e-09
INTERP      -8.802189e-01  6.968719e-03  3.170767e-03 -4.652036e-11
EVENT       -4.073329e-01  3.170767e-03  4.176038e-03 -2.049346e-11
logSigma     5.874470e-09 -4.652036e-11 -2.049346e-11  1.250000e-01
```

I have tried converting the EVENT field to a numeric value but this still does not work.

```
X = data.table(EVENT=as.Date(c(ISOdate(2011,1,1),ISOdate(2011,1,2),ISOdate(2011,1,3),ISOdate(2011,1,4))),
               VAL = c(12.2,62.4,38.9,65.7),
               INTERP = c(126.42,124.26,125.53,124.48))
X[,EVENT := as.numeric(EVENT)]
CEN = censReg(formula=log(VAL) ~ INTERP + EVENT,data=X)
vcov(CEN)
            (Intercept) INTERP EVENT logSigma
(Intercept)         Inf    Inf   Inf      Inf
INTERP              Inf    Inf   Inf      Inf
EVENT               Inf    Inf   Inf      Inf
logSigma            Inf    Inf   Inf      Inf
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Why are you using `censReg` when you have no censoring?

Comment: Because i have a more complex dataset that DOES have censored data.  Since i wasn't able to get that to work i tried to use a dataset that does not have censored data since the results will essentially be the same as a basic linear regression.  that way i could troubleshoot and find out where the problem is.  I stated that at the beginning of my post.

Comment: Generally survival analysis is done with intervals, i.e. time differences from the beginning of an observation interval, rather than raw dates. Your first call to `censReg` implied that you had observed the cases since the "beginning of time", although that would only be back to 1970 in the case of R Dates.

Comment: Thank you.  I modified the code to work with datediff as opposed to date and that corrected the std. error issue.